# Canonical transformation of 2-body hamiltonian into center of mass and translation components. How to gain an expressions for the conjugate momenta?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am trying to transfom a quantum hamiltonian as detailed in this website. It starts of by using the classical hamiltonian and conjugate momenta:

$$ H\equiv \frac{p_1^2}{2m_1}+\frac{p_2^2}{2m_2}+V\left(\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2\right) $$

I am confused as how you gain the conjugate momenta:
\begin{align}
\mathbf P&=\mathbf p_1+\mathbf p_2 \\
\mathbf p&=\frac{m_2\mathbf p_1-m_1\mathbf p_2}{m_1+m_2}
\end{align}

provided the change in co-ordinates:
\begin{align}
R&=\frac{m_1\mathbf r_1+m_2\mathbf r_2}{m_1+m_2} \\
\mathbf r&=\mathbf r_1-\mathbf r_2
\end{align}

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You understand canonical transformations preserve the form of quantum commutators and PBs, right?

Comment: Hi Cosmas, and thank you for your comment.
By that do you mean how {F,G} in the old variables (q,p) is the same as {F, G} in the transformed variables (Q, P) are the same? If so then I think I understand - this is such that the dynamics of the system will be the same after the transformation is applied, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the very definition of a canonical transformation!